# Centering columns in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to create a simple css grid using the native CSS Grid properties. It works as I wanted, except I want to create a utility class that can center a column in a grid.

Is there a way to create the `__centered` utility class, so that I can apply it to center columns? I know I could add empty column divs before the column, but I want a cleaner solution.

```css
.l-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1196px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 52px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  background-color: orangered;
}
.l-grid--col {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
}
.l-grid--col-1 {
  grid-column: auto/span 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-2 {
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-3 {
  grid-column: auto/span 3;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-4 {
  grid-column: auto/span 4;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-5 {
  grid-column: auto/span 5;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-6 {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-wrap">
  <div class="l-grid l-grid__centered">
    <div class="l-grid--col-2">
      <p>This should span 2 and be centered.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To clearify, I want to create a utility class much like the `.centered` class found in Zurb Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#centered-columns (Except only for css grid's)

Answer (score 10):

CSS Grid provides the [**`justify-items`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#row-align) and [**`justify-self`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#row-align) properties, which can be used for aligning grid items along the row-axis.

`justify-items` applies to the grid container. `justify-self` applies to grid items.

So your utility class can look something like this:

```
.l-grid__centered {
    justify-self: center;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

This tells the grid item to center itself on the row in a grid area spanning from the first to last columns. ([Negative integer values on `grid-column` and `grid-row` start the count from the end side.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement))

```css
.l-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1196px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 52px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  background-color: orangered;
}
.l-grid--col {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
}
.l-grid--col-1 {
  grid-column: auto/span 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-2 {
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-3 {
  grid-column: auto/span 3;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-4 {
  grid-column: auto/span 4;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-5 {
  grid-column: auto/span 5;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.l-grid--col-6 {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

    .l-grid__centered {
        justify-self: center;
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="l-wrap">
  <div class="l-grid l-grid__centered">
    <div class="l-grid--col-2">
      <p>This should span 2 and be centered.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/k846f3kz/8/)

*NOTE: The utility class is applied to the grid item, not the grid container. Also, this method breaks the 2-column grid area of the original content. The centered content will be able to expand across the entire row.*

---

Alternatively, when working with a six-column grid, to horizontally center a two-column grid area, your utility class can look like this:

```
.__centered {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
 }
```

OR

```
.__centered {
  grid-column: 3 / -3; 
 }
```

```css
.l-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1196px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.l-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 52px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  background-color: orangered;
}

.l-grid--col {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
}

.l-grid--col-1 {
  grid-column: auto/span 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-grid--col-2 {
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-grid--col-3 {
  grid-column: auto/span 3;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-grid--col-4 {
  grid-column: auto/span 4;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-grid--col-5 {
  grid-column: auto/span 5;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-grid--col-6 {
  grid-column: auto/span 6;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-grid__centered {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-wrap">
  <div class="l-grid">
    <div class="l-grid--col-2 l-grid__centered">
      <p>This should span 2 and be centered.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/k846f3kz/10/)

*NOTE: This solution only centers even-numbered grid areas.*

Comment: Yes, justify-self: center; seems to workout pretty well. But my editor (vscode) does not recognize it yet as official and MDN shows a lot of question marks for browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self. Can we still safely use it?

Comment: @ChristofKälin, check [caniuse.com](https://www.caniuse.com) for browser support tables and, more importantly, test your code across browsers yourself.

Comment: i could not understand why grid-column: 3 / span 2; makes it center while by theory, it should start on 3rd track and span 2 column so it should end on 5th track. isn't it?

Comment: Your first fiddle is flawed. Your piece of text "This should span 2 and be centered." is exact width of 2 columns. Try "This should span 2 <br/> and be centered."  and your first fiddle doesn't work anymore :( Here's a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7kb598a2/1/)